# Save RDD[Row] as file in scala

Tags: scala, csv, row, hard-drive

I made RDD[Row] data(myData) and try to save it as file

```
myData.saveAsFile("path")

output
(a, 100, testcontenct)
(b, 200, stackoverflow)
```

It works well but since it will be treat as csv, I need to take out '(' and ')' symbol. 
My final goal output is

```
a, 100, testcontenct
b, 200, stackoverflow
```

How do I make output file without these symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use databricks csv library: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

I think it only works on dataframes, but you can easily convert your RDD to a dataframe with

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val myDf = myData.toDF
```

then write it to a file with

```
myDf.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .save("path")
```